# In codeigniter is it possible to write query in a view file

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Is it possible to write query in view file of CodeIgniter?
Like the code below.

```
<?php

    $query= $this->webpages->get_where_custom('parent_id',0);
       foreach($query->result() as $row){
          $query1=$this->webpages->get_where_custom('parent_id',$row->id);
               foreach($query1->result() as $row1){
                   $row1->id;
               }
       }
?>
```

Comment: Yes, you can execute and check. ?

Comment: you can execute the query but you can't call the controller function in view file. please check it before using that

Comment: Yes but it is horrible practice. The view file should not be concerned with logic and you could just have tried?

Comment: thats not MVC anymore

Answer (score 2):

The query runs without any problem.

But functions doing the querying tasks for you in the model are capable of being used simultaneously from everywhere in your application.

Your view file is also a PHP file and is able to connect to the database with the setting you have in your config file, but it doesn't actually go with the concept of `MVC` pattern.

You can yet use `AJAX Calls` to get you the data you need in your view file!

Note: In this case, since the query is not ran from the model, the `database` class must be `autoloaded` or loaded in the controller and not in the model.

Comment: I am new to Codeigniter. I want live search how can I do it in Codeigniter?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to show query in view file?

Anyway, To print the last executed query:

```
echo $this->db->last_query();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can write query in view but its not standard and also in controller but model is best for query execution. If you run query in view so there isn't any difference in normal application and MVC based pattern application where you separate the model for database operation, view for viewing and controller for control the model and view.

Simply controller is a bridge for model and view. So best way is write the queries in model instead of controller or view.

And remember `$this` keyword will not work in view because when we create model or controller we extend the classes `class My_model extends CI_model` **OR** `class My_controller extends CI_Controller` so `$this` reference the current method or object so if you don't extend model or controller you can't use model or controller functions so `$this` keyword won't work without extending classes of model or controller.

Answer (score -1):

You could try this...

```
<?php
 $CI =& get_instance();
 $query= $CI->webpages->get_where_custom('parent_id',0);
   foreach($query->result() as $row){
      $query1=$CI->webpages->get_where_custom('parent_id',$row->id);
           foreach($query1->result() as $row1){
               $row1->id;
           }
   }
?>
```

It's not according MVC rule but it's possible.